# Anaconda command prompt won't launch

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've installed the Anaconda3 64 bit on my windows 10 64 bit.
Added to environment variable the path and script directory as well. Installation was successfull.
When I type `anaconda` in command prompt it give me the following
[image]

Neither of any application of navigator launch, when I click a loading bar appears for 2-3 seconds and disappears without opening program.
And one more thing, when jupyter program runs, from which directory does it runs, I mean if I have `program.py` how can I run it via jupyter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do when launching anaconda? In my experience (on a mac) you use `conda` for (primarily) installing and managing python packages within your anaconda installation.

If you are trying to open an python interpreter, try typing `ipython`.

In answer to your **jupyter** question, it should run from whatever directory you call it from. See [here](http://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute.html) for details.

Comment: I'm having difficulty on installing scipy package, that why I've to use conda

Comment: So scipy is usually included in the anaconda installation. This command should help you install it if not installed `conda install scipy`. This [link](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html) should give you some more help :)

Comment: I don't want to use scipy with anaconda3, rather I want to use it in a regular python which I downloaded from the site

Comment: It _should_ be the case that scipy installed via conda is available to your normal python distribution.

Comment: that's the actual problem, it is not working with my normal python distribution, is there any way to make it work ?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you installed anaconda from the exe supplied on their site. I have a few questions so I can help more. Did you install scipy as an aside from the conda install? How are you trying to launch python? And finally, could you provide an example of how you are trying to import scipy, and the error you are getting from it?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with what _wheel_ is. Do you have a link to the installation instructions (anaconda distro, and scipy) so that I can assist further?